# Detect opened windows/tabs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, window

I have an application window that displays a button. On button click, a new tab is opened with window.open javascript function and later I would like to be able to detect if that link is opened or not and if it is, I need to close that window. Can this be done in Firefox ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why specifically in FF? Are you developing an extension, or are just simply concerned that it works for that particular browser?

Comment: I have a custom application build for a company that is accessed only with Firefox, and that's the way I would like it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.open()` function returns a `Window` object. Just call `close()` on it:

```
var childWindow = window.open(....);

...

childWindow.close();
```

Comment: But check it first: if (childWindow && !childWindow.closed) childWindow.close();